# Why does Eclipse Mars not read the project location correctly?

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a project that has lived in my workspace for some time.  It is a git project and I use Egit and cygwin git to manage it.  Not sure if that's relevant.

I'm not sure what's messing up eclipse but, in the last day, I have noticed that when I start eclipse, my project is marked as closed.  When I looked at the project properties, I saw that eclipse is using the wrong path.  Instead of:

```
C:\cygwin64\home\rcoe\git\projectname
```

it is now pointing at:

```
C:\cygwin64\home\rcoe\.gitconfig\projectname
```

However, my `.metadata` `.location` file (which is binary) shows that the location is correct.  This file is buried in my workspace, which is located in my Windows home directory.

I tried deleting my project and re-importing it, both as a git project and as a general project, and it opens no problem.  I can even close and open eclipse right away and the project stays open.  However, give it a few minutes and re-open eclipse and the project now thinks it lives under a non-existent `.gitconfig` directory.  I even tried creating a new workspace and importing my project.  Same behaviour.

So, I'm not sure whether this is an Eclipse Mars bug, or Egit, or something else.  Has anyone seen this kind of behaviour before?

**Edit:**
I hit new snags trying to share my project using Eclipse 4.4.  The Luna git plugin threw errors about the plugin.  So I went back to Mars (4.5) and created a new workspace.  The `.location` file looks like this

```
@±‹#¼ %–ç£“¾ 2URI//file:/C:/cygwin64/home/rcoe/git/logprocessing              ÀXûó#¼ QóŒ{»wÆ
```

but when I open Eclipse, the properties of the project looks like:

```
C:\cygwin64\home\rcoe\.gitconfig\logprocessing
```

I have no idea what Eclipse is using for its location, if not the `.location` file.

Comment: I downloaded the current Mars zip, kept my old workspace, deleted my old .project file and recreated it, using my git project home as the root directory.  Project pointed to the right place.  Restarted eclipse - SAME PROBLEM.Then, I deleted my project, told eclipse to go ahead and delete the contents (because it pointed at the non-existant .gitconfig location), and re-imported local git project:

     org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException:

    Could not write file: C:\cygwin64\home\rcoe\.gitconfig\logprocessing.
    Could not write file: C:\cygwin64\home\rcoe\.gitconfig\logprocessing.

Comment: one more edit....after a clean install, the import of my project is saved in the metadata .location file with .gitconfig in the path.  So as soon as the project files are created, the location is messed up.  So eclipse has the correct reference when it's first imported but as soon as eclipse is restarted, the project cannot be found, because of the bad path in the .location file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what looks to be a solution.  I moved the `.gitconfig` file from my cygwin home, which is where Eclipse was configured to look for it.  On starting Eclipse, I was able to import my project without error.  And even though Eclipse's previous error messages implied it wanted to write to the project directory beneath a .gitconfig directory (cf. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473782), Eclipse did nothing of the sort.

I am now able to restart Eclipse, run my unit tests, etc., without error.  I am also able to interact with my Git repo using Eclipse, even though Eclipse no longer points at my .gitconfig and so does not know my user.name or user.email properties.

Comment: Good feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, it would be best to use [git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) instead of git in Cygwin. It comes with Git 2.4.6 released 5 days ago.

That way, Eclipse doesn't have to manage two different filesystem, and two different HOME (`C:\cygwin64\home\rcoe` vs. `%USERPROFILE%`)

Comment: I think this is more of an eclipse plugin problem.  I downloaded the last Luna (4.4) build and created a new workspace.  The project can be imported using the EGit plugin, from a local repo, and the metadata that eclipse creates (the .location file) points at the correct path.  Doing the same operations with the Mars build (4.5) consistently fails.  If I had to guess, an eclipse update caused a regression bug.

Comment: @RobinCoe Ok. Still, using git for Windows is more practical (and comes with 200+ unix commands as well)

Comment: I'm curious what makes Git-for-Windows better than Cygwin?  I've been using Cygwin for over 15 years and it's never failed me.  It has a plethora of linux tools and great package management.  I am curious about GFW and have installed it.  There is definitely cleanup to do, because it looks like it uses my $HOME env variable, which points at my Cygwin home.  So, if it gives me a small set of tools that I get in Cygwin, but Cygwin has TONS more, why is there a GFW?

Comment: @RobinCoe If its just for Git, you don't need cygwin which is way slower than the more recent and lightweight msys2. But if you are using cygwin for other packages than just git, then sure, keep using it.